# Are free Artinian modules finitely generated?

Tags: vector-spaces, modules, solution-verification, free-modules

I think the answer is yes. Let $M$ be the Artinian free $R$-module.

*Proof.* Let $S$ be a basis of the free $R$-module M. On the contrary, if $S$ were infinite, then we could pick an infinite sequence of pairwise distinct elements from $S,$ e.g., $s_1, s_2,$ etc.

From this, we have the strictly decreasing sequence of $R$-submodules $M_1 \supsetneq M_2 \supsetneq \cdots,$ where $M_i = R \langle s_j \,|\, j \geq i \rangle.$ However, this contradicts the assumption that $M$ is Artinian.

Is the proof valid? If so, can we then conclude that Artinian vector spaces are finitely generated?

Comment: You shoul take a little care when picking the elements, so that the modules generated by them are different. For instance take a part of a basis.

Comment: If they are distinct wouldn't the modules generated by them be different. S is supposed to be the basis of M

Comment: If $S$ is a basis there is no problem, but you only said a generating set.

Comment: Yes you're right I changed it accordingly.

Comment: Yes, this is exactly correct. Very nicely done. +1